# is software-search.net ethically clean

Tags: download, file-download

While browsing, that is, to be more exacty, while searching
for a possibility to download visio, I came across
http://www.software-search.net/shop/search/?s=Microsoft+Office+Visio .
Now, I have sort of a bad feeling about that site, so I was wondering
if they're ethically clean or if this is just a site where people
get ripped of and/or distributes pirated software.

So, if somebody could give advice if I should use this site I'd be
very grateful.

BTW, forgive my poor tagging, but I had no idea what other tags to use.

Comment: @Hello71 - it is about if a site is genuine/official for software and not a web application. I think it should be ok here.

Comment: He's not asking about the website; he's asking about their product.  I think the question fits here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope - See sites like this all the time, all pirate. Avoid at all cost.

... As a reseller, I can tell you that cost price for physical media is much higher. Microsoft, Autodesk and other large companies do not authorise anyone to resell digital only copies (usually) and the only place to get a discount for doing it is by going direct - but even still, I doubt it would be as cheap as this place!

Most likely the software they sell is the same as if someone went to torrents and downloaded themselves, all they (most likely) are doing is packaging the keygen/crack together, making it look official and hoping enough people purchase without realising there is anything wrong.... And by the time they do, they would have started a new shop under a different name.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. Just wanted to be sure.

Comment: Yep, I've run across the exact same site under different domains before.  Here's a similar question on another forum: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=689243

Answer (score 0):

Looks VERY fishy...on their "About" page, they show their address as:  300 Atlantic Street Stamford CT., with a picture of a beautiful commercial building at that address, but they are NOT registered at that address...and their IP address GEO-LOC is PARIS, FRANCE.

Answer (score 0):

Im on the fence on this one, bought and downloaded, ran it with Microsoft Authentication Tool, allowed me to connect to get updates, called just to make sure, say they buy bulk OEM , ususally from companies gone under in different countries, as long as it goes on New computer, they say legit?